# AJAX AsynchFileUpload stop upload process

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, asyncfileupload

ASP.net website using AJAX AsyncFileUpload

Hello Experts,

In my web page I have only two controls, one is a textbox for the user to enter a template name and the second one is an AJAX AsyncFileUpload.

When the user clicks on the "Browse" button of my AsynchFileUpload control and selects a file, I'm validating the Textbox for "Empty field" using the "OnClientUploadStarted" event. **If the textbox is empty, I want to stop the upload process of the AJAX Control.**

After some research I found a link in this forum where an user implements **sender._stopLoad()** method inside the function that handles the "OnClientUploadStarted" event. After applying the same logic, the function stops the load process, but I'm getting the following alert box from the browser:

**Unhandled Exception: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined**

I have no split method being used in my code. This error appears when using _loadStop() method from the AJAX asynchfileupload. Here is the code that I'm using:

JavaScript Function to handle event:

```
function FileUpload_BeforeUpload(sender, args) {
   if ($get('<%=TemplateNameTextBox.ClientID%>').value == "") {
       sender._stopLoad();
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TableRow>
   <asp:TableCell>Template Name:</asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TemplateNameTextBox" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
   </asp:TableCell>
   <asp:TableCell>
       <asp:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1"      
                OnClientUploadStarted="FileUpload_BeforeUpload"/>  
   </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

I have tested my code in all main browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome) and I get the same error message. Have you guys come across this issue? and if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks for your help.

YPC.

Comment: http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/upload-file-with-asp-net-asyncfileupload-ajax-control-inside-modalpopupextender/

Answer (score 1):

Show your message because i had the same problem, the way I fix that was to add the right client event to the ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload control: `OnClientUploadError="UploadError"` and catch the event in the JS code:

```
var ifIgnoreError;

function UploadError(sender, e) {
  if (ifIgnoreError) {
    alert("Wrong file type");
  } else {
    alert(e.get_message());
  } 
}
```

Good Luck.